# TYPO3 - Hide "Reset user settings to default state" Button in with UserTS

Tags: typo3, lts

I try to hide all fields in the user-settings, that should not be accessible for non-admins.

In the Tab `Edit and advanced functions`, i've hidden all fiels with this UserTS:

```
setup {
    fields {
        startModule.disabled = 1
        edit_RTE.disabled = 1
        resizeTextareas_Flexible.disabled = 1
        resizeTextareas_MaxHeight.disabled = 1
        titleLen.disabled = 1
        thumbnailsByDefault.disabled = 1
        edit_docModuleUpload.disabled = 1
        showHiddenFilesAndFolders.disabled = 1
        copyLevels.disabled = 1
        recursiveDelete.disabled = 1
    }
}
```

After that I realized that there is a button on the bottom, that has no table-definition that I can find out by the chrome developer console:

[image: German Backend]
[image: English Backend]

Does anyone know a way to hide this button with UserTS, to make the whole Tab disappear?

Thanks :)

Comment: are you sure you want to hide the option to reset the user config? it could be necessary to clear the preset data of a user. it holds the default settings for some BE modules, e.g. it holds the state of the page tree (fold/unfold for each page). most popular situation to reset is something for admins only: select in log module way to much records to display (unlimited): you only can use the log module again if you reset your user settings. If you have a very big page tree setting all pages to unfold will slow down the BE. resetting user data will clean up.

Comment: The field will stay visible to admins. I only want to hide it for the "normal" users.
But thats a good point.